# SQL to filter for records more than 30 days old

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following query:

```
select customer_name, origination_date
where origination_date < '01-DEC-2013';
```

I would like to select all customers that have an origination date older than 30 days. Is there a way in SQL (oracle, if specifics needed) to specify it in a more dynamic approach than manually entering the date so that I don't need to update the query every time I run it?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336354/subtracting-n-days-from-a-date-using-sql

Comment: @dvnrrs -- looks like this post needs to know the built-in function for current date, not covered at the other post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Oracle, when you subtract dates, by default you get the difference in days, e.g.

```
select * from my_table where (date_1 - date_2) > 30
```

should return the records whose date difference is greater than 30 days.
To make your query dynamic, you parameterize it, so instead of using hard coded date values, you use:

```
select * from my_table where (:date_1 - :date_2) > :threshold
```

If you are using oracle sql developer to run such a query, it will pop up a window for you to specify the values for your paramteres; the ones preceded with colon.

Answer (score 3):

Sure try something like this:

```
select customer_name, origination_date where 
origination_date >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETUTCDATE());
```

This basically says where the origination_date is greater or equal to 30 days from now.  This works in Microsoft SQL, not sure but there is probably a similar function on Oracle.